# Android 4.1 Gradle Build Failed

Tags: gradle, android-studio-4.1

I am having issues running my project after upgrading to the latest version of the android studio. I've tried deleting my .gradle file and rebuilding the project but I still get the same error. Here is the error that it gives me.

[image]